# Bind an EXE file to a directory?

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, exe

Is there anyway to bind an EXE file to a directory in a way that when the user tries to open said directory the EXE will run first without opening the directory first?

I am trying to make a simple file locker (folders with password) and I was wondering if its possible to make a gui like tkinter appear before the directory is opened to the user, without a script running constantly in the background?

Comment: This is no ordinary task and isn't done in a few lines of code. In addition I would not recommend python to solve it. Why don't you use a `.zip` file and have a password ? It is free to use, well known, crossplatform and relatively secure.

Comment: it can be complex task because user can use many different methods to access folder - ie. different File Managers, command `cd` in console, code in different scripts, etc. It may need to add it in system code - so you have to know how systems works. And it may need to admin privileges.